# Regex to find digits between the last set of parentheses

Tags: php, regex

i was struggling to make a regex which extract the digits bettween the last set of parentheses from a string, and this is what i came with until now:

```
^.*?\([^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*\).*$
```

E.g.:

```
This is, (123456) a string (78910);
```

It returns 123456 , which is great but i need it to look at the last set and return 78910.Also , i want the regex to ignore everything but digits:

```
This is, (123bleah456) a string (789da10);
```

Should return:  78910

**UPDATE**

Using regex:

```
(\d+)(?!.*\d)
```

For string:

```
Telefon Mobil (123)Apple iPhone 6 128GB Gold(1567)asd234
```

Will return 234 when it should be 1567

[Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/J1ZtBhkyuC)

Comment: *Wiktor Stribiżew closed this question because he thinks it's a duplicate* - **It was a duplicate**. `(\d+)(?!.*\d)` worked well with the examples you  provided. Now, you say the digits you need are inside the last `(...)`. Surely it is a different story.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , if you would have read it closer , you would have seen that i said that from the beginning,it is not a different story,even in the title it's mentioned that the digits are between parentheses.I removed my comment even though it was not offensive at all,it reflected your action.You marked as duplicate a question that was not everywhere near that

Comment: Still, the answer is almost the same - [`\((\d+)\)(?!.*\(\d+\))`](https://regex101.com/r/8jgAfp/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew also i don't like that you edited my question where i explained why i used a different regex on the update.That's power abuse.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , on the other hand , \((\d+)\)(?!.*\(\d+\)) won't return the  last parentheses's digits if it contains anything else other than digits.e.g (123mda321)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/8jgAfp/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , now it returns the last set of digits inside parenthese , but i need all digits inside to be extracted,ex: (123mda456) result: 123456 .

Comment: Then you cannot do it with one regex *matching* operation. Extract the last parentheses with a digit inside, and remove all the digits as a second step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the last one by use of [greed](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
.*\(\K\d+
```

[See demo at regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/ZU90HW/1)

[`\K` resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match.

For your more specific updated case slightly modifiy the regex and strip out non-digits.

```
$str = "This is, (123bleah456) a string (789da10);";

if(preg_match('/.*\(\K\d[^)]*/', $str, $out))
  $res = preg_replace('/\D+/', "", $out[0]);
```

[See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/676124)

Comment: That's great , but what if my paranthese contain something like this (123mda2456) . In this case i also need to extract only the numbers 123456 . How would you do that?

Comment: boblbebubble: *[https://regex101.com/r/8jgAfp/2] returns the last set of digits inside parenthese , but i need all digits inside to be extracted,ex: `(123mda456)` result: `123456`.*

Comment: @PeterCos In this case use something like `.*\(\K\d[^)]*` and strip out non-digits with `preg_replace` and `\D+` on your result `$out[0]`.